# Site down after root drive expanion on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, rdp, root

I have expanded the root drive of an EC2 windows instance machine.
Now after re-attaching the drive and firing up the instance, i cannot RDP into the instance as the site is down which as being hosted on the EC2 machine instance.

Has anyone faced this before??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, but generally speaking the only way to grow partitions is by copying the ephemeral root to another EBS instance, and then booting off the new instance, throwing away the original. If you didn't do this (or got it wrong), it won't boot at all.